# Finding the directional derivative for an arbitrary vector

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$f(x, y) = 
\cases{
    \frac{xy}{x+y}& if $x+y\neq0$  \\
    0 & if $x+y=0$
}$$

Find the directional derivative $∂_uf(0, 0)$ for an arbitrary vector $u = (u_1, u_2) ∈\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{(0, 0)\}.$

Ive been stuck on this question for a couple of hours now and cant seem to get far in it so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By definition we have:

For $u=(u_1,u_2)$ where $u_1+u_2\ne0$

$$\partial_uf(0,0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(tu_1,tu_2)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{u_1u_2}{u_1+u_2}=\frac{u_1u_2}{u_1+u_2}$$
and for $u=(u_1,u_2)$ where $u_1+u_2=0$, clearly $\partial_u f(0,0)=0$.